# Why does iframe content height render differently when using "src" vs "srcdoc"?

Tags: html, css, iframe

When comparing the `src` and `srcdoc` behavior of iframes, I came across a difference that I could not explain: a div with 100% height renders as the full height of the iframe when I use `src=[data uri]`, but not when I use `srcdoc`.

The code to reproduce this is simple, and can be seen here: https://codepen.io/jamadeo/pen/LYJMzEG

Using src + inlined data URI, the div is the full height of the iframe:

```
<iframe src="data:text/html,<div style=&quot;background-color: red; height: 100%&quot;>hello, world</div>"></iframe>
```

Using srcdoc, the div is only the height of its contents.

```
<iframe srcdoc="<div style=&quot;background-color: red; height: 100%&quot;>hello, world</div>"></iframe>
```

I would expect them to render equivalently. Looking at differences in behavior of src and srcdoc turns up plenty of information on cross-origin behavior and browser support, but nothing about rendering.

Comment: Here's another way to see the discrepancy: https://codepen.io/jamadeo/pen/WNgLXwe

The dimensions as returned by document.body.offset{Width,Height} are consistent for width, but not height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`srcdoc` is implicitly generating a standards mode document, while `src` isn't. For equivalence, you need to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the start of the `src` data.

For the exact rules, see [HTML living standard, 13.2.6.4.1 The "initial" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-initial-insertion-mode) and note the parts which say "if the document is not an iframe srcdoc document, ..."

```html
<iframe src="data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><div style=&quot;background-color: red; height: 100%;&quot;>hello, world</div>"></iframe>

<iframe srcdoc="<div style=&quot;background-color: red; height: 100%;&quot;>hello, world</div>"></iframe>
```